# Sum of Factorials

Tags: summation, contest-math, factorial

> What is the hundreds digit when 2014! + 2013! + ... + 3! + 2! + 1! is expressed as an integer?

I was hoping to find out some sort of pattern by trying the first few factorials, but far as I can see there's none. Also, there seems to be some formula for this, but I'm not really sure if I understand them. How would I solve this?

Comment: Eventually the last three digits of a factorial are $\ldots 000$.  When?

Comment: Note that for $n$ large enough, $n!$ ends in 000. How large is large enough?

Comment: If you do it the way Yves Daoust did, you can even add it up by hand easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that for $n\ge15$ the factorial will end upto $000$ ,

($15!$ or more contain $125=5^3$ as a factor and when this multiplied by $2^3$ will lead to $000$ at the end)

so we need to find hundreds digits of $14!+13!+12!+......+1!$ and this is equal to $313$ because the sum is $93928268313$ and so the **hundreds digits** of $$2014! + 2013! + ... + 3! + 2! + 1!$$is **313**.

Comment: For the sum of 14! + 13! + 12! + ... + 1!, did you just do it by hand?

Comment: Refer to the answer by @Yves Daoust.

Answer (score 6):

Perform the computations modulo $1000$ (no calculator required):

$$\begin{align}1!&\equiv1,\\
2!&\equiv2,\\
3!&\equiv6,\\
4!&\equiv24,\\
5!&\equiv120,\\
6!&\equiv720,\\
7!&\equiv40,\\
8!&\equiv320,\\
9!&\equiv880,\\
10!&\equiv800,\\
11!&\equiv800,\\
12!&\equiv600,\\
13!&\equiv400,\\
14!&\equiv600,\\
15!&\equiv0.
\end{align}$$

Then the sum (easier backward)

$$313.$$

Comment: Warm thanks for the anonymous downvote.

Comment: Why the down vote, this answer is right.

Comment: @Priyatham: yep. I think I a was also the only one to suggest modular arithmetic, which makes it computable mentally.

Comment: OP may have down voted because they don't know modular arithmetic?

Comment: @Priyatham: and leave no comment because they cannot type :)

Comment: @YvesDaoust: You should know by now that random downvotes happen. They are presumably cancelled by all those random upvotes that nobody complains about. Don't let it bother you!

Comment: @TonyK: God yes, I know. The downvoter got  the message I guess.

Comment: Nice answer! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Compute $15!$ and note the three last digits.

Comment: You forgot to instruct to drop the last two digits.

Comment: Well, it was a *hint*.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the hundreds digit of a number if you know the remainder when divided by $1000$. Can you see that if $k$ divides $n_0!$ then $k$ divides $n! \, \, \forall n \geq n_0$?

If that's clear then note that $15!$ is divisible by $1000$ and you have your answer.